# Replace same version WiX bundle with different options

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I want to write a burn bundle that preconfigures my product for different clients. To make their installation as easy as possible, I want to create different bundles for each client that install the same packages but with a different set of registry values.

Now I got a `MsiPackage` that accepts input via `MsiProperty`. I have a default burn bootstrapper that sets this property to a value that I pass on the command line with light `-dproperty_a=value_a`.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="Product Name" 
            Version="!(bind.packageVersion.main)" 
            Manufacturer="!(bind.packageManufacturer.main)" 
            UpgradeCode="{MYGUID}">

        <WixVariable Id="property_a" Overridable="yes" Value=""/>

        <BootstrapperApplicationRef
            Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
                LicenseUrl="" LogoFile="bitmaps/logo.png"
                ThemeFile="burnTheme.xml"/>
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
            <MsiPackage SourceFile="package.msi" Id="main">
                <MsiProperty Name="property_a" Value="!(wix.property_a)"/> 
            </MsiPackage>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Everything works like expected. But if I install two different versions one does not replace the other. Two times the same product is installed.

I thought that using the same `UpgradeCode` should prevent this. Why is it possible that two bundles with the same `UpgradeCode` are installed?

Can I ensure that the installation of an alternate version uninstalls another version before the installation? Is there something like `AllowSameVersionUpgrades` for burn bundles?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please make sure to increment the bundle version number in the second package? This will ensure that it upgrades the previous version and remove it.

Comment: Yes this would help. But all my bundles should have the same version since they are only different flavors of the same bundle. It is like one installer with different languages. If you install a software like Microsoft Office in English on one machine it will automatically replace the French version. Afterwards you are able to replace it again with English. If I create two bundles with the same version number and the same UpgradeCode but different contents. They coexist next to each other.

Comment: I found http://wixextba.codeplex.com it supports same version upgrades. Maybe it solves my problems.

Comment: Exactly the default BA doesn't support this, you can write your own BA or use the one mentioned above from third party's.

Comment: I was wrong, wixextba also does not handle same version upgrades. Looking at the code of burn, I found the line where it does the comparison. So not just a custom BA is needed, but a custom burn engine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check what is wrong with your upgrade, I assume you are building a Major Upgrade, in that case, you have to keep UpgradeCode same and change the ProductCode, Product Version and Package Code, refer to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2005/08/22/454552.aspx) blog on how to build your upgrade so that it replaces the existing product

Comment: This is true for MsiPackages. I am struggling with a burn bundle. I can define a UpgradeCode but no ProductCode. http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd%5Cwix%5Cbundle.html

Comment: Also I am not trying to do an upgrade. I just want to install another type of my bundle on top of itself. Same version but different settings. Imagine two versions of one tool in a big bundle which should not be installed at the same time. In my case these are predefined servers that have to be put in the registry. The is no new or old version there is just A and B. When I install A, the old B should be removed.

Comment: Your understanding about Burn bundle is incorrect. Burn itself is not a product, it will not install itself. Burn is a chainer, that will install list of products (MSI packages). If you are planning to ship A as newer version of B, then you have to build A as a major upgrade of B, and include B in your new burn package.

Comment: @GangadharHeralgi Burn is also a package manager. It installs itself, too. Upon uninstall, it can uninstall packages that are no longer used by any bundle.

Comment: @TomBlodget Exactly. Using burn I have one package manager that is listed as one entry in the Control Panel. I want to have another bundle that reconfigures or replaces the first one. But there is no order. The packages should behave like a software that is distributed in different languages.